# Assigning a number to a level in cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make a method that adds a number to another number. This number will be assigned to the game level, and as the number goes up, the game gets harder. At the end of each level, I will play this method, and therefore the level number will go up. I know that this is really simple, I just can't seem to get my head around it, don't laugh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want a method that will increase a ivar?

```
@interface Game : NSObject {
    NSInteger level;
}
@property (readonly) NSInteger level;
- (void)nextLevel;
@end

@implementation Game

@synthesize level;
- (void)nextLevel {
    level++;
}
@end
```

Comment: I thought that they'd be a simpler way. Something like a value, that you call say, levelvalue, that increase by 1 when the method is called.

Comment: thats exactly `nextLevel` does. all you need to do is add an ivar (`level`) to your class and add method that increate the ivar (`nextLevel`)